# how to show article comment contains (php codes) as string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

hi sorry for my language.
im using laravel 5.6 to create a simple article site.
i have a problem with show article comments as string. the problem is : laravel try to render php codes and the page give me some errors.

imagine a user wants to send his laravel code as comment to me:

(this is just an example)

```
@foreach($article->tags as $tag)
<a class="tags" href="/tags/{{ $tag->slug }}">{{ $tag->title }}</a>
@endforeach
```

if user send this codes as comment to me, my page not loading and give me errors

my code to show comments :

```
{!!$comment->body !!}
```

help me please . thank you

[image: my view file to show all comments]

Comment: Can you show the whole view file and also give an example of what is stored in `$comment->body`?

Comment: for example the comment is exactly that foreach code I've written above.
and i attached my screen shot right now

Comment: Can you give an example of what is stored in the database for `$comment->body`?

Comment: so you want to escape the output so it doesn't break html ?

Comment: @lagbox yes is want to show exactly that codes. without render them. the problem is from rendering php codes. not htmls

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data   tada

Comment: i tried it . its not working ....

Comment: "its not working" describes nothing

Comment: i mean i have same errors . and my page show nothing

Comment: what "ERRORS"? you are not providing any errors

Comment: @lagbox https://www.programdan.ir/err.txt

Comment: what information do you need? :|:|:|:|

Comment: i have that errors in my console :|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found the problem :

problem is for laravel blade codes.
like: @foreach . @if . @auth and ....

i have to scape this codes with space :
@ foreach . @ if and ....

Answer (score 1):

Replace `{!!$comment->body !!}` with `{{$comment->body }}`.

When you use `{!! !!}}`, the template engine tries to parse the contents within the braces. Use `{{ }}` so that the contents are displayed as it is escaping all html.

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: .....
it tries to render my comment php code into my page

Comment: Can you post the entire error message? It might include some clue.

Comment: Did the above error message appear when you used ```{!! !!}}``` or ```{{ }}``` ?